# Python seconds trim off from hours

Tags: python, odoo

Let me have idea to achieve the following in Python

```
total_hrs = datetime.timedelta(hours=total_hrs)
```

This will result in 3:52:30 . But i need to trim off seconds. this should in the format of 3:52:00

Comment: What's the original content of your `total_hrs` variable?

Comment: total_hrs=3.875  this float value actually

Answer (score 3):

```
result = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(total_hours*60))
```

Comment: that's a bit neater than my way!

Answer (score 1):

```
total_hrs = datetime.timedelta(hours=3.875)
print str(total_hrs)
>>> 3:52:30

# Split into components
total_hrs_split = str(total_hrs).split(':')
print total_hrs_split
>>> ['3', '52', '30']

# Trim off seconds
total_hrs_trimmed=datetime.timedelta(hours=int(total_hours_split[0]),
                                     minutes=int(total_hours_split[1]))
print str(total_hrs_trimmed)
>>> 3:52:00
```